# Array processing / prediction in DAX (powerpivot)

Tags: powerpivot, dax

See the table below :

```
          1       2       3
2011    100     125     155
2012    120     160 
2013    110     X=?
```

What this means is that the figure for values originating from 2011 was 100 in 2011, then 125 in 2012, and 155 in 2013.

For 2012 the value was 120 in 2012 and 160 in 2013

For 2013 the value was 110 in 2013

I want to predict the value X for items originating fom 2013 in 2014 by projecting forward the average development from year 1 to year 2 in 2011 and 2012  of the  2013 value 110 ie

```
X = ( (125+160)/(100+120) ) * 110
```

This would be easy enough wiith cell references in Excel.
Any ideas on how I would do it with DAX?

(This algorithm is known as a "Chain-Ladder" in the world of insurance)

Answer (score 0):

A calculated measure that elegantly solves this problem would require a separate Date table, so that you could use the PREVIOUSYEAR function. Similarly, you *probably* wouldn't want to name columns for previous years "1,2,3,etc.." - it would be more elegant to unpivot the dataset so that there are two date columns - e.g. "Value Date" and "As Of Date".

You could then set up a calculated measure that would, for any cell referenced in a pivot table, look up the average of values for previous years, effectively creating the chain-ladder .